# Increment in for loop has no effect

Tags: java

I have this code

```
public class CountHi {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "abc.xyz";
        System.out.println(s1.length());
        System.out.println(xyzThere(s1));
    }
    public static boolean xyzThere(String str) {
        if (str.length() > 3)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 3; i++) {
                System.out.println(str.substring(i, i + 4));
                if (str.substring(i, i + 4).equals(".xyz"))
                {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have been searching from the last hour or so, but couldn't find out a possible reason that the `i++` has become dead code. Actually I am new to programming and java so please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you already know, you can use str.contains(".xyz") to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Why do you say it is dead code? Does it show in your IDE?Where do you get that

Comment: ur code will be executed only once.so it not executing i++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `if loop` always will go outof the function, because the `return`.

You should use a boolean variable, and put the return at the end of the method.

Declare a global variable:

```
boolean result = false;
```

Then use it in yout if loop:

```
            if (str.substring(i, i + 4).equals(".xyz"))
            {
                result = false;
            } else {
                result true;
            }
```

Add the return at the end of the method:

```
return result;
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you are returning on the very first iteration of the `for` loop, the `i++` part will never be executed.

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length()-3;i++) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(i,i+4));

    if(str.substring(i,i+4).equals(".xyz")) {
        return false;

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Either of your `if` or `else` block will be executed, and they both return immediately. So the loop doesn't get chance to iterate again.

I don't understand the point of the loop out there. If you just want to check the extension is `.xyz` or not, you can do it with a single substring.

```
if (s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf(".")).equals(".xyz")) {
    // true
}
```

---

Or if you just want to test, if your string contains `.xyz`, then simply use `String#contains()` method:

```
s1.contains(".xyz");
```

Comment: @Rohit..Actually I am in learning phase & trying to solve this question "Return true if the given string contains an appearance of "xyz" where the xyz is not directly preceeded by a period (.). So "xxyz" counts but "x.xyz" does not. "

Comment: @Gaurav. Then you can directly do - `s1.contains(".xyz");`. That will work fine. If you have some more dynamic part in that, then you would probably need a regex.

Answer (score 1):

while looping if condition `if(str.substring(i,i+4).equals(".xyz"))` is satisfied or not satisfied, it will **return** from loop in any case. and `i++` is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

you need to keep

```
        System.out.println(str.substring(i,i+4));
```

within `{}`